# Горизонтальное меню навигации с отцентрованными элементами

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать меню с помощью LI и отцентрировать текст ссылок. И чтобы отступов между ссылками не было. Но, к сожалению, ничего не выходит: текст не выравнивается по вертикали, и отступы между элементами сохранились.

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #333; 
  height: 100px;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a>some</a></li>
    <li><a>some</a></li>
    <li><a>some</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Что тут сделано не верно. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: для LI добавил "line-height:100px" но не работате line-height:100%, получается как-то не адаптивно... есть более правильный вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. inline-block

1) Если высота меню `100px`, то однострочные пункты можно отцентрировать по вертикали с помощью `line-height: 100px;`.

2) Инлайн-блоки ведут себя как слова в предложении: оставленные между ними пробелы и переводы строки превращаются в лишние просветы. На английском СО собраны [способы борьбы с этой напастью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/).

```css
ul.menu {
  background-color: #333; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">some</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="#">some</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="#">some</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### 2. table-cell

Можно заставить пункты меню вести себя так, будто они ячейки таблицы:

```css
ul.menu {
  background-color: #333; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @simplygood Добавил исправленное решение через инлайн-блоки.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
ul.menu li {
  float: left;
}
ul.menu a {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.menu a:hover {
  background: silver;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">some1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">some2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">some3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вам воспользоваться flex.

```css
ul.menu { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333; 
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
}

ul.menu li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  width:75px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a>some</a></li>
    <li><a>some</a></li>
    <li><a>some</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: С flex ведет себя (по мойму) как обычный div, без всяких выравниваний, в итоге воспользовался line-height:100px; и писал теги без переноса на новую строку